# Possible collisions of asynchronous unit tests against a test database in Mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js

I am new to the javascript ecosystem, and I am trying to wrap my head around a decent way to do some basic <strike>unit</strike> testing against the REST API using a stored set of fixtures, i.e. `.json` files.

My entry point sets up a testing environment by connecting to a test database and emits a `ready` state.

```
if (!process.env.TESTING) {
  /* Connect to MongoDB */
  connect(process.env.DEV_DB_HOST, process.env.DEV_DB, () => app.emit(ready));
  app.on(ready, () => {
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}!`));
  });
} else {
  connect(process.env.TEST_DB_HOST, process.env.TEST_DB, () => app.emit(ready));
}

export default app;
```

Once the connection is established, the collection recreated in the test database using fixtures and the tests are executed.

```
import Paper from '../models/paper.js';

describe('Home Page', () => {
  before(async() => {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      app.on(ready, () => resolve());
    }).then(async() => {
      try {
        await Paper.collection.drop();
      } catch(error) {
        /* Mongo throws an exception if the collection in question does not exist */
      }
      await Paper.create(fixtures);
    });
  });

  after(async() => {
    await Paper.collection.drop();
  });

  it('Returns a list of items ordered by date in descending order', async() => {
    const response = await chai.request(app).get('/');
    expect(response.body).to.have.lengthOf(2);
    expect(response.body).to.be.sortedBy("date", { descending: true });
  });
});
```

If I replace the `before` and `after` hooks with `beforeEach` and `afterEach`, since the tests are `async`, is it possible that the hook gets executed for a test and dumps out the collection before another test, which is using the collection, finishes executing? If so, what is a good way to go about populating a test database with fixtures for each test case?

Comment: Unit testing shouldn't have any side effects so to say. Unit testing basically tests the inputs and outputs of the smallest units of work possible (i.e. a single function) where it dependencies are mocked/stubbed. What you are doing is more along the lines of integration / api functional testing.

Comment: For the test data, it depends if you want to reuse the same collection for each tests in the suite (`describe` block). If you want a refreshed data set before each test (`it` block), then `beforeEach` and `afterEach` is the better way to go and the tests should only execute after those hooks

Comment: In the better scenario, wouldn't a collection get deleted from under an `it` block, since the tests are `async`? If an `it` block is guaranteed to run to completion before the next one is fired, then this works fine, but if they are running in parallel, then `beforeEach` might fire for some `it` block and drop a collection from under another `it` block. Is this correct?